# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2018' in position 15564: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies, python-poetry

When I try to execute the `poetry add pyarrow` command in the directory where my poetry.lock file is I get the following error (see title).

I tried using a specific or the lastest version of poetry but the error stays there.
I have the latest version of poetry and python version 3.9.1.

This happens just for this module, all the others are okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it as well and also get an error, but it is different. It is working for me with `python3.8` though. Maybe you can use that version. [The documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html#installing-from-source) also doesn't mention `python3.9` as a compatible version.

As an alternative you can install the nightlies from [this repo](https://gemfury.com/arrow-nightlies/python:pyarrow). I quickly tested it with poetry and it works. [This poetry resource](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/) might be helpful to set that up. You have to set this in your `pyproject.toml`:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pyarrow"
url = "https://repo.fury.io/arrow-nightlies/"
```

and then run `poetry add --allow-prereleases pyarrow`.

Comment: Yeah definitely it was a problem with the python version. I switched to 3.8.x and the problem vanished. Thank you.